# How to submit a macOS app to app Store without sandboxed?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, sandbox

I like to know if there is a guideline or some special way to submit a macOS app to app store without having sandbox, let say you have an app that you need to remove sandbox to this app works, is there a special treatment for that if we want submit our app to app store? or there is absolute no way for submitting a macOS app without sandbox and we have to lunch it as third party on a custom website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit a macOS app to the App Store without being subject to sandboxing as it is right now.

Ofcourse, it is possible that Apple would make a special exception for you - but in general, I would say that's not at all likely.

Comment: So you say there is a way that apple accept my app without sandbox if I follow some procedures provided by apple?

Comment: No, I’m saying the rules state that it must be sandboxed… however if you happened to develop Microsoft Office or Adobe Photoshop, it is possible that Apple could bend the rules in your favor. For a random third party developer, it’s not going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

### Appropriately Sandboxed

Apple requires all applications submitted to the Mac App Store to be sandboxed, see [section 2.4.5](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#2.4.5) of the App Store Review Guidelines:

> **2.4.5** Apps distributed via the Mac App Store have some additional requirements to keep in mind:
>
> (i) They must be appropriately sandboxed, and follow macOS File System Documentation. They should also only use the appropriate macOS APIs for modifying user data stored by other apps (e.g. bookmarks, Address Book, or Calendar entries).

The language suggests exceptions are possible. [Talk to Apple directly](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) and explain your situation.

**Plan to be denied an exception.** Spend your time working within Apple's requirements, or build your [own store](https://store.dssw.co.uk) and [build your own business](https://indie.miln.eu).